# Cakephp2. save data is adding two more rows

Tags: cakephp

```
public function index($tin=null) {
    $this->layout = 'index_1';
    $this->loadModel('Insurance');
    $this->loadModel('Verification');
    $this->loadModel('Insurance_price');

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $verification_fee=$this->Insurance_price->findByInsurance_type("Third Party Auto Insurance");
    $ver = $verification_fee['Insurance_price']['verification_amount'];
    if(!empty($tin)) {
        $this->request->data['tin'] = $tin;
        $this->request->data['amount'] = $ver;
        $this->request->data['date'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $this->Verification->save($this->request->data);
        $this->Verification->clear($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

That's my controller. I am trying to save those data once the page loads.

But when I check the database table instead of seeing only 1 new record I see 3 new rows with the same data as 'amount' and 'date', except for tin column which will have 'image'.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Which record do you see 3 times? Verification?
Can you show the content of $this->request->data before you use the save function

Comment: I echoed it and it gave me only one result. but whem saving into the verifications table. I see 3 new rows

Comment: This code will insert new record into the verification table for every page load, with the same data. If you refresh the page multiple times, you will get more records. The data insertion and modification should be done with POST request.

Answer (score 0):

try inserting

$this->Verification->create();

before

$this->Verification->save($this->request->data);

And check

Comment: I did that initially before I removed it

Comment: Is this an Ajax Call? if it is ..then try writing exit; at the end of the function.